# Where is the DOM XML package for PHP 5?

Tags: php

Is there any `DOM XML` package available for `php5` as  `php4-domxml` in the case of `php4`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DOM is [included by default](http://www.php.net/manual/en/dom.installation.php) in a PHP installation:

> Installation
>
> This extension is enabled by default.
>   It may be disabled by using the
>   following option at compile time:
>   --disable-dom

Looking at the [build rules](http://git.debian.org/?p=pkg-php/php.git;a=blob;f=debian/rules;h=0a561b44668abef43af8c9d186fd081b8321dbc2;hb=HEAD), DOM is neither disabled, so it should be available.

Answering your question: no, there is no package like php4-domxml because PHP 5 includes it by default.